# Serenity BDD Report Project Name as variable

Tags: maven, testing, automated-tests, serenity-bdd

When our reports are generated and we view the HTML output in a browser the project name in the top right of the report is currently a hardcoded value which is set in the serenity.properties file:

`serenity.project.name=Project Name`

It would be nice to be able to give each test report a project name set from some environment variables such as:

`serenity.project.name=${environment} + " " + ${ProjectName}`

Is this possible in a Maven project?